# srpring + angularJS возвращает 500 при post запросе

Tags: angularjs, spring

Здравствуйте. У меня есть приложение spring +angularJS.  AngularJS http.post() запросом отсылает данные на контроллер, контроллер их обрабатывает и возвращает ответ.

Вот код ангуляра который отсылает запрос на контроллер.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("controller", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sendInputs = function (word1, word2, word3) {
        $http.post("<c:url value='/getVals'/>", JSON.stringify({word1: word1, word2: word2, word3: word3}))
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.rows = data;
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
            });
    };
});
```

код контроллера

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "getVals", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<ResponseData> test(@RequestBody RequestData requestData) {        
        List<ResponseData> responseDatas = new ArrayList<>();
        responseDatas.add(new ResponseData(requestData.getWord1() + " answer1", requestData.getWord2() + " answer1", requestData.getWord3() + " answer1"));
        responseDatas.add(new ResponseData(requestData.getWord1() + " answer2", requestData.getWord2() + " answer2", requestData.getWord3() + " answer2"));
        return responseDatas;
    }
```

в pom файле включил jackson

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

вот сами передаваемые сущности

```
public class RequestData {
    private String word1;
    private String word2;
    private String word3;
    // геттеры сеттеры
}

public class ResponseData {
    private String answerWord1;
    private String answerWord2;
    private String answerWord3;
    // конструктор
    // геттеры сеттеры
}
```

*На localhost'e все работает просто отлично.* Однако, при деплое на удаленный компьютер код перестает работать и при запросе на контроллер сыпет следующую ошибку.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:265)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:232)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:173)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:130)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Версия спринга 4.3.2.RELEASE, попробовал поменять версию jackson'а на 2.8.5 - не помогло.
Вы не знаете в чем может быть причина того, что на локалхосте все работает, а при деплое на удаленный сервер - нет?

Comment: В браузере нажмите f12 и перейдите на вкладку network, проверьте, правильные данные передаются или нет. Добавьте в вопрос версию спринга, возможно эта версия не совсем совместима с Вашей версией  jackson-databind

Comment: Судя по Вашему стектрейсу, у объекта `ObjectWriter` нет метода `forType` (он появился в jackson начиная с версии 2.5), проверьте на вашем удаленном сервере наличие в папке `lib` библиотек `jackson`-а, ну и попробуйте версию jackson ниже 2.5, напр. 2.4.4